# How can I test for ConfigureAwait(false) in a unit test for async methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, deadlock

I have some async library methods where it is important the `ConfigureAwait(false)` be used "all the way down". I'd like to write an NUnit test that verifies that this is so. How can I do that? I imagine that I'd have to somehow hijack the synchronization context with a custom implementation?

Comment: I don't think there's a better option than a custom synchronization context.

Comment: Don't you trust `ConfigureAwait(false)`? Or do you want to assert that it was called? What do you mean with "all the way down"? Can you give a code example of what you're trying to test?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible. You could create a custom synchronization context (see striked answer below), but it would only check the first awaited call. If the first awaited call called uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the continuation will run on a different thread, which won't have a `SynchronizationContext`, so it won't be possible to check whether subsequent async calls use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not.

---

<strike>Indeed, a custom synchronization context seems to be the only way. Here's a possible implementation:</strike>

```
class TestSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public bool PostCalled { get; private set; }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        PostCalled = true;
        base.Post(d, state);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        PostCalled = false;
    }
}
```

You can then write your test like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestFoo()
{
    var context = new TestSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    FooAsync().Wait();
    Assert.IsFalse(context.PostCalled);
}
```

if `PostCalled` is true, it means that the `SynchronizationContext`'s `Post` method was called, which shouldn't happen if `ConfigureAwait(false)` was used.

Comment: Wouldn't this only check that the final outer layer's `ConfigureAwait(false)` was used? This would not check that it was used "all the way down" (but I may be wrong, if I am wrong could you add some detail to your answer why to help me learn too :) )

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, you're right. It seemed to work for a simple scenario, but actually it doesn't work if a method in a lower layer doesn't use ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But it will.  The only reason it wouldn't check "all the way down" is if some of the code further down changes the current synchronization context, or explicitly runs code in another context in some way.  While that doesn't *technially* test that every single `await` uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it *does* properly test that the current synchronization context is never captured and used, which I would imagine is the *actual* goal.  If the code, at some level, does a `Task.Run` and then awaits without `ConfigureAwait` it's likely not a *problem*.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque You should probably override both `Post` and `Send`, just to be verbose.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I don't think `await` ever will, but (I presume) the *actual* goal here is to avoid the use of the current synchronization context.  While the expected primary use case will be `await`, it should work even in the event other tools are used that interact with the synchronization context.  And in any case, it's just three lines of code.

Comment: Wouldn't something like changing the value of `TaskScheduler.Default` (using reflection) help? Though it's certainly very hacky solution.